# The theme implementations may not be rendered until all modules are loaded on custom module

Tags: hooks, 9, log-messages, theme-negotiation

I'm attempting to load a custom page where I call an external API to retrieve the response and format it into the .html.twig file. However, I've frequently encountered a 50x server error. Upon reviewing the recent log messages, I found the following error.

> Exception: The theme implementations may not be rendered until all
> modules are loaded. in Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (line
> 139 of Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php).

Even after reloading, the page is taking an excessive amount of time to load.

Kindly suggest me to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! All information necessary to derive an answer must be in the Question. The Question alludes to a custom page and to an external API, but does not provide technical details as to the meaning of those.

Comment: What is unclear about the error message? It's probably your attempt to format the html.twig file which you are doing far too early instead of letting the Drupal theming level do it automatically at the right time.